# Resource not found on grails application with cache plugins

Tags: caching, grails, plugins

I have installed cache-header (1.0.4) and cached-resources (1.0) in our grails application and once in a while we receive messages like the one below.

Do you have any clue on why do we get those messages and how can we fix it?

Regards

> 2013-09-24 04:21:34,561 [catalina-exec-2] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta 
>   - CENTRALLEAD - Resource not found: /LNEjLROINsk9TKAzkAwtTxIXru6CyGZP4s5w1mybXkD.js
>
> 2013-09-24 04:21:30,030 [catalina-exec-5] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta 
>   - CENTRALLEAD - Resource not found: /ZCCuNwL3Y8SsQanoiqrQWpsP4q9q7JN3IDqeB4FsIve.css

My configuration looks like:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////      Resources
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = [
    '/images/*',
    '/css/*',
    '/js/*',
    '/plugins/*'
]
```

**EDITED**

There is something really weird.
The image that we most get the error is: 
http://bemdireto.com.br/static/BkSQHPEr6mihRHkVPfr5gl9Dkq02wsucDobLXxgHaao.jpg

we have also set at the config:

```
 grails.resources.work.dir = "/www/logs/tmp/centrallead"
```

and the image is present at that folder

We hava a load balancer and the image is present in all servers

Comment: Is this happening every time? Might be a dead process looking for it while you have cleaned your cache.

Comment: It's not happening every time. I couldn't figure out a pattern

Answer (score 0):

It can be the resources work dir that was cleaned up, or a wrong cache. Normally when I use the cached-resources I do the following (in *Config.groovy*):

- `grails.resources.debug=true`: only for development mode. With that you will avoid weird cache issues when changing a lot your files during the development
- `grails.resources.work.dir`: Define a fixed directory for the temporary files. This is important in production, and will evict this errors of resource not found, because the default is the temporary folder of your container, and it can be cleaned by the container.

Comment: can it be, somehow, related to resources on emails sent from the system?

Comment: Can you elaborate more your question? The resources plugin is the same if you use it in a view or email.

Comment: Yes, I know, but if I send an email and then deply a new version of the application, once the user opens that emails the resource might not exists anymore

Comment: Yeah, in this case I think it's better to have fixed links to this files. Use the `grails.resources.adhoc.excludes` config, declaring the folder of your email resources.

Comment: Sergio, I haven't figured it out yet. This error bothers a lot. I happens more than 100 times a day and may hide important ones

Comment: Have you tried the grails.resources.adhoc.excludes config? What's the links produced by resources in your email?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it